# Library resources in Android projects built with Ant

Tags: android, ant, resources

In my workspace I have 3 Android projects. One core library and two projects to build two versions of my app: free and paid. Now I have several strings, which should be different in the projects. In every project I have values/strings.xml file where e.g. "*@string/version*" is defined as follows: "*library*" in library project, "*free*" in free project and "paid" in paid project.
If I build free and paid projects with Eclipse I get "*free*" and "*paid*" for "*@string/version*". Everything is OK. But if I build my projects with Ant I get ALWAYS "*library*" for "*@string/version*".

What I'm doing wrong? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show your ant script?

Answer (score 1):

When you build with Ant, use `ant clean install` or `ant clean debug`, and see if that helps.